# Problema no codigo - SQL Developer

Tags: sql, tabela-banco-de-dados, oracle11g

As seguintes tabelas apresentam erro:

```
CREATE TABLE REQ_ROB_EQP ( 
    REQ_PER_ROB_ID NUMBER,
    REQ_EQU_NOME VARCHAR(100),    
    CONSTRAINT REQ_ID_NOME_PK PRIMARY KEY (REQ_PER_ROB_ID, REQ_EQU_NOME)
    --CONSTRAINT REQ_PER_ROB_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (REQ_PER_ROB_ID) REFERENCES ROB_ROBOTICO(ROB_PER_ID),
    --CONSTRAINT REQ_EQU_NOME_FK FOREIGN KEY (REQ_EQU_NOME) REFERENCES EQU_EUIPAMENTO(EQU_NOME)
);

CREATE TABLE MOD_ARM_FOR ( 
    MOD_ARM_NOME VARCHAR(100), 
    MOD_FOR_MODELO VARCHAR(100),    
    CONSTRAINT MOD_NOME_MODELO_PK PRIMARY KEY (MOD_ARM_NOME, MOD_FOR_MODELO),
    CONSTRAINT MOD_ARM_NOME_FK FOREIGN KEY (MOD_ARM_NOME) REFERENCES ARM_ARMA(ARM_NOME),
    CONSTRAINT MOD_FOR_MODELO_FK FOREIGN KEY (MOD_FOR_MODELO) REFERENCES FOR_FORMA(FOR_MODELO)
);
```

as tabelas referenciadas existem e estão funcionando perfeitamente. Cheguei a comentar a fk para ver se era algum erro ali, porem o problema persiste. Segue o erro:

> Error report - ORA-00904: "REQ_PER_ROB_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

da segunda tabela:

> Error report - ORA-00904: "MOD_ARM_NOME": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Testei seu código aqui e funcionou sem problemas.

Comment: Ou você tira as aspas de tudo ou mantém as as aspas em tudo.Veja aí. Eu aposto uma pacoquinha que o que esta dando erro são as aspas. rsrs

Comment: Aqui nao funciona..e é exatamente o mesmo codigo, eu copiei e colei!

Comment: Já tentou rodar no SQLPlus? Esta me parecendo alguma configuração do SQLDeveloper.